# Android SQL app unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I have followed the following tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8TaTgr4uKM) to create an SQL database app, unfortunately i am having an issue where the app doesn't open, can anyone help and see if i'm doing something wrong.

This is the SQL Code

```
package com.example.sqltest2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "productstable.db";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Aisle";
    public static final String COL_4 = "LOC";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMAY KEY    AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, Aisle INTEGER, LOC INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

The Logcat points to syntax error on

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMAY KEY     AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, Aisle INTEGER, LOC INTEGER)");
}
```

Comment: `PRIMAY KEY`? prima **R** y, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:  The main issue is probably what @Marc B pointed out, `PRIMAY` should be `PRIMARY`.

I also noticed this:

Your `TABLE_NAME` has `.db` in it.

Change this:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "productstable.db";
```

To this:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "productstable";
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marc's and Daniel's responses; your `CREATE` statement needs a space.
`"create table" + TABLE_NAME +"` will produce something like `create tableproductstable`. Place a space after `table` to have `"create table " + TABLE_NAME + ...`